# nw.gui - TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined in gui.Window.open

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, window-object

Using node webkit, I'm trying to open a new window from the click of a button in the initial window, and at various points write to a textarea in the new window when running node.js code in the initial window context.

The initial window (index.html) contains the following js:

```
        window.gui = require('nw.gui');
        var win = gui.Window.open('console.html', {
          position: 'center',
          width: 1000,
          height: 280
         });

        win.on ('loaded', function(){
            var parameters = {greeting: "Hello World"}
            win.emit("data", parameters);
          });
```

This is part of a function which is called by the button click, which should create a new window, and then emit variables which can be listened for in the new window.

console.html is setup with the following:

```
    <section>
        <div class="log_window">
            <textarea id="log_output" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
    </section>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            var gui = require('nw.gui');
            var win = gui.Window.get();
            win.on("data", function(data) {
                document.getElementById('log_output').value = data.greeting;
            });  
      </script>
```

When the button is pressed, I get the following error:

```
win.on ('loaded', function(){
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

I really don't know what's going on here - is there an issue with the event contexts?